# getting only column borders using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML Table. and her i want to get only first row border and the rest only column borders only. as given in the screenshot. please let me know how i can do it in my css.

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="topbotcol">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">
                <span class="font-style-bold">Item</span>
            </th>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">
                <span class="font-style-bold">Qty</span>
            </th>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">
                <span class="font-style-bold">Unit</span>
            </th>
            <th valign="middle" class="colsep rowsep" align="center">
                <span class="font-style-bold">Rate $</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">
                <div class="para">BUILT-UP WATERPROOF MEMBRANE PANEL ROOFING TO FLAT ROOFS AND POOL DECK</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">
                <div class="para">Preparing surfaces: priming and applying “Grims K1” slurry and “Grims Premier K10” waterproof membrane system as specified</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">
                <div class="para">Membrane collars; pointing with epoxy; reinforced with clamp rings around flanges of rainwater outlets</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowsep" align="left">
                <div class="para">A</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">
                <div class="para">200mm diameter</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">
                <div class="para">13</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">
                <div class="para">No.</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">
                <div class="para">34.28</div>
            </td>
            <td class="rowsep" align="center">
                <div class="para">445.64</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks[image]

Comment: What do you mean by get? Please add the css you currently have trying to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting the border on the td and th cells, but making the border-top and border-bottom none for the td, but then setting surrounding border of the entire table as well.

The following css is an example:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}

td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Link to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianlynch/Esb6r/)

Answer (score 2):

```
table {
    border-top: 1px Solid Black;
    border-left: 1px Solid Black;
    border-bottom: 1px Solid Black;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
    border-right: 1px Solid Black;
}
th {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px Solid Black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo classes here:

As your table has `th` for table headers then you can try this:

```
table.topbotcol tr:first-of-type{
     border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;   // Will apply border to first row
}
table.topbotcol tr:first-of-type td{
     border:none;  // will not apply border to tds of first row, and continue after first row
}
```

You haven't provided detailed description, i think this might help you!

[**Pseudo-Classes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

### Docs

[:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is set a border and set the table border to collapse. This will merge the cell borders. Then remove the unwanted top and bottom borders.

```
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}    
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with a fuller example as well as some more optimizations.

Link to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhavar/Kp3v6/)

Suggestions:

- don't use valign or align on table cells, use CSS vertical-align and text-align instead
- use paragraph tags instead of `<div class="para">`
- use class names that are descriptive of the content, not its style. This helps with maintenance later when you decide that you do not want something to be `font-style-bold` anymore. It is easier to change `<th>` in the CSS than it is to change it in the CSS and THEN go back and change ALL `font-style-bold` to `font-style-normal` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/aYCjA/

```
.tbl {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tbl th, .tbl td {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.tbl td {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.tbl th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The important thing here is `border-collapse: collapse`. This attribute prevents showing duplicate borders in sibling cells.